# Get values from keys from a decode Json array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [artRef] => TEX00006
                    [artDesc] => ESPONJA MICROFONE FACE CORTADA P. SCALA RIDER/SRC
                    [qttStock] => 82
                    [dateStock] => 2020-01-25T11:59:26.2337248+00:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [artRef] => TEX00006
                    [artDesc] => ESPONJA MICROFONE FACE CORTADA P. SCALA RIDER/SRC
                    [qttStock] => 1
                    [dateStock] => 2020-03-31T00:00:00Z
                )

        )
)
```

This is my decode json array now i want to get the values from qttStock and dateStock in a loop or foreach ? i can only get the first array [0] how can i get all the values in case of the array have more than one [qttStock] etc ?

Comment: `foreach ($array[0] as $innerArray)`

Comment: Is there a reason why the array is nested 2 levels deep?

Comment: Use nested loops to process both levels of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops.

```
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $element) {
        echo "{$element['qttStock']} on {$element['dateStock']}<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your questions!
Please try:

```
for($x=0;$x<count($array);$x++){
    echo $array[0][$x]['qttStock'];
    echo $array[0][$x]['dateStock'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi @Barmar but when the array has only one level i get a lot of warnings

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [artRef] => 4990003325
            [artDesc] => VISEIRA SCHUBERTH C3/S2 PREP. P/ PINLOCK ESPELHADA (IRIDIUM)
            [qttStock] => 2
            [dateStock] => 2020-01-25T13:23:45.3420766+00:00
        )

)
```

Warning: Illegal string offset 'qttStock' in /home3/mvital/public_html/app/siemet/wp-content/plugins/woo-show-stock-from-xml/inc/functions-api.php on line 156

Warning: Illegal string offset 'dateStock' in /home3/mvital/public_html/app/siemet/wp-content/plugins/woo-show-stock-from-xml/inc/functions-api.php on line 156
4 on 4

Warning: Illegal string offset 'qttStock' in /home3/mvital/public_html/app/siemet/wp-content/plugins/woo-show-stock-from-xml/inc/functions-api.php on line 156

Warning: Illegal string offset 'dateStock' in /home3/mvital/public_html/app/siemet/wp-content/plugins/woo-show-stock-from-xml/inc/functions-api.php on line 156
V on V

Warning: Illegal string offset 'qttStock' in /home3/mvital/public_html/app/siemet/wp-content/plugins/woo-show-stock-from-xml/inc/functions-api.php on line 156

Warning: Illegal string offset 'dateStock' in /home3/mvital/public_html/app/siemet/wp-content/plugins/woo-show-stock-from-xml/inc/functions-api.php on line 156
2 on 2

Warning: Illegal string offset 'qttStock' in /home3/mvital/public_html/app/siemet/wp-content/plugins/woo-show-stock-from-xml/inc/functions-api.php on line 156

Warning: Illegal string offset 'dateStock' in /home3/mvital/public_html/app/siemet/wp-content/plugins/woo-show-stock-from-xml/inc/functions-api.php on line 156
2 on 2